# Benefits of Salesforce integration with GitLab over Salesforce DX?

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, ci

[Salesforce has partnered with GitLab](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy):

> Salesforce DX tools enable test automation and continuous delivery, but getting started can be daunting. We have partnered together to provide templates that make GitLab’s CI/CD work out of the box, easy to customize, and integrate well with GitLab’s other leading capabilities, such as project planning, testing, and security.

But, what are the things Salesforce can achieve with GitLab but not with DX with respect to only CI/CD activities (not other capabilities like project planning, testing, and security)?

Answer (score 2):

The [announcement](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/05/gitlab-salesforce-devops-made-easy.html) lists the benefits. If you are starting from scratch on CI, then this looks like a good way to go given the documentation and convenience features.

We have been using Jenkins for many years and so are sticking with that, but have had to invest time in SFDX-specific tooling - https://github.com/claimvantage/sfdx-jenkins-shared-library. And there are certainly other CI products you could consider.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce DX and GitLab are different, complementary products.

Salesforce DX does not by itself provide any CI/CD functionality. You can think of the Salesforce DX infrastructure and `sfdx` CLI as providing build services, which can be used both in and out of a CI flow. You'd use Salesforce DX locally to build and work within development orgs, while in a CD/CD flow you'd use Salesforce DX to generate environments to build and test your application. The CI/CD capability is separate from DX itself.

GitLab is a CI/CD provider, with no specific Salesforce capabilities to its platform as such. It adds orchestration of automated build and deploy workflows that *use* Salesforce DX, in the same way (well, very roughly) that a C or C++ project might use `make`.

What Salesforce is now providing is templates for CI/CD pipelines that use Salesforce DX on GitLab's platform. These templates streamline the process of building a GitLab CI/CD flow around Salesforce DX for a Salesforce project.